# Nginx rewrite %20

Tags: redirect, nginx

I'm trying to add a rewrite rule to fix the %20 issue in urls and replace it by a '-' **AND** replace any capital letter by a lower case letter at the same time.

Example:

> www.mysite.com/channels/channelidnumber/Funny%20Videos/ to
>   www.mysite.com/channels/channelidnumber/funny-videos/

I tried the following but this only removed the %20 without replacing it and nothing else.

```
rewrite ^(.*)(\s|%20)(.*)$ $1$3 permanent;
```